# Trying to figure out the best index possible for this SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table that contains 300,000 rows of test data, and I'm trying to come up with an appropriate index for this select statement, however I do believe nothing will work very efficiently and I might need to adjust my approach.

x and y can be anywhere from 1 to 9, and p can be literally any value above x * y (so x of 4 and y or 4, equals 16, but it could be any value above that, there would be no limit.  An x of 1 and y of 1 might have a p of 1000, or might just be 1.  Another x of 9 and y of 9 might be a p of 81, might be 100, might be 10000, it has no limit.)

```
SELECT `x`, 
       `y` 
FROM   `table` 
WHERE  `x` <= '9' 
       AND `y` <= '9' 
       AND `used` = '0' 
ORDER  BY `p` DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

I've created an index that of...

```
x, y, used, price
```

... which works brilliantly well for specific values of x and y, but when asking for a range, this obviously takes a lot more work.

Can anyone see an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Why is price in the index if its not being used?

Comment: Sorry, p is the price, my mistake.  The index is x, y, used, p

Comment: Try a stand alone index on x and y

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'asking for a range' ? are you asking the user to input the range ?

Comment: My PHP code will choose the value of x <= ? and y <= ?, so those values will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT `x`, `y`
FROM `table`
WHERE `x` <= '9' AND `y` <= '9' AND `used` = '0'
ORDER BY `p` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note: If any of the values are numbers, then drop the single quotes for the comparison. Under some circumstances, comparing strings and numbers can make it harder for the optimizer to do its work.

This is no great index.  The best is on `(used, x, y, p)`.  The query will still require a file sort.  One problem is the inequalities in the `where`.  The second is that MySQL does not implement the `desc` option for columns in an index.

Comment: I would say it depends on columns cardinalities. If there are only two values for `used` column (1 and 0) - i wouldn't put it in the index, at least not at the first place

Comment: @MaxU . . . In this case, the `=` sign drives the choice of putting it first.

Comment: i know, but making FTS or, better using another indexes, might be more efficient,

Answer (score 0):

There 3 possible indexes.  But the optimizer is unlikely to *consistently* pick the best.  All start by filtering on the one useful thing `used=0`

```
INDEX(used, price)  -- This scans from top price down; it wins if
                    -- a good x&y are found soon
INDEX(used, x)  -- This wins if there are few rows with x<9
INDEX(used, y)  -- This wins if there are few rows with y<9
```

If you have simplified the query, then all bets are off.  Especially in the following:

By having a "covering index", you get an added boost:

```
INDEX(used, price, x, y)
INDEX(used, x, y, price)
INDEX(used, y, price, x)
```

That is, if you *really* have `SELECT x,y,z FROM ...`, then these are no longer "covering", and (because of being bulkier) are worse.

Add the 3 indexes and hope that the Optimizer guesses right.

Note:  Is `used` a true/false flag?  Do not use `INT` for flags; it takes 4 bytes.  Use `TINYINT` or `ENUM`, they take only 1 byte.